# $(1+x)^r \le 2^{r-1} + 2^{r-1}x^r, x>0,r>1.$

Tags: inequality, geometric-inequalities

Do someone know an elegant proof for the inequality:
$(1+x)^r \le 2^{r-1} + 2^{r-1}x^r, x>0,r>1.$

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(x)=x^r$ is a convex function in $(0,+\infty)$ for $r>1$, by Jensen's inequality,
$$\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)^r\leq \frac{1+x^r}{2},$$
i.e.
$$(1+x)^r\leq 2^{r-1}+2^{r-1}x^r.$$